# How to slice an array around its minimun

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to define a function that finds the minimum value of an array and slices it around that value (plus or minus 5 positions). My array looks something like this:

```
[[ 0.          9.57705087]
 [ 0.0433      9.58249315]
 [ 0.0866      9.59745942]
 [ 0.1299      9.62194967]
 [ 0.1732      9.65324278]
 [ 0.2165      9.68725702]
 [ 0.2598      9.72263184]
 [ 0.3031      9.75256437]
 [ 0.3464      9.77025178]
 [ 0.3897      9.76889121]
 [ 0.433       9.74167982]
 [ 0.4763      9.68589645]
 [ 0.5196      9.59881999]
 [ 0.5629      9.48861383]
 [ 0.6062      9.3593597 ]]
```

However, I am dealing with much larger sets and need a function that can do it automatically without me having to manually find the minimun and then slice the array around that.I want to find the minimun of the array[:,1] values and then apply the slicing to the whole array.

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.argmin()` to get the index of the minimum value. This will do it using the second column only (you haven't specified if it's the minimum value across columns or not).

```
your_array[:np.argmin(your_array[:, 1]), :]
```

To slice it 5 values further than the minimum, use:

```
your_array[:np.argmin(your_array[:, 1]) + 5, :]
```

Comment: I think OP is asking for `i = np.argmin(...); your_array[i-5:i+5, :]`

Answer (score 0):

Given your objective array:

```
import numpy as np

anarray = np.array([[ 0., 9.57705087],
                    [ 0.0433, 9.58249315],
                    [ 0.0866, 9.59745942],
                    [ 0.1299, 9.62194967],
                    [ 0.1732, 9.65324278],
                    [ 0.2165, 9.68725702],
                    [ 0.2598, 9.72263184],
                    [ 0.3031, 9.75256437],
                    [ 0.3464, 9.77025178],
                    [ 0.3897, 9.76889121],
                    [ 0.433, 9.74167982],
                    [ 0.4763, 9.68589645],
                    [ 0.5196, 9.59881999],
                    [ 0.5629, 0.48861383],
                    [ 0.6062, 9.3593597]])
```

This function will do the job:

```
def slice_by_five(array):
    argmin = np.argmin(array[:,1])
    if argmin < 5:
        return array[:argmin+6,:]
    return array[argmin-5:argmin+6,:]

check = slice_by_five(anarray)
print(check)
```

Output:

```
[[0.3897     9.76889121]
 [0.433      9.74167982]
 [0.4763     9.68589645]
 [0.5196     9.59881999]
 [0.5629     9.48861383]
 [0.6062     9.3593597 ]]
```

The function can certainly be generalized to account for any neighborhood of size `n`:

```
def slice_by_n(array, n):
    argmin = np.argmin(array[:,1])
    if argmin < n:
        return array[:argmin+n+1,:]
    return array[argmin-n:argmin+n+1,:]

check = slice_by_n(anarray, 2)
print(check)
```

Output:

```
[[0.5196     9.59881999]
 [0.5629     9.48861383]
 [0.6062     9.3593597 ]]
```